# Hide Dropbox icons from the Finder menu

Tags: macos, finder, icon, dropbox

is it possible to remove Dropbox's icons from the Finder context menu ?

[image: Finder contextual menu]

I just want to be able to see the text and not the icons. I can't find anywhere in the settings to do this. Any other possible ways?

Comment: Don't think that's possible. It's an implementation Dropbox itself wrote and it's all or none

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the dropbox settings there is an option to enable finder integration(the third checkbox from the top). Just uncheck it, no restart needed. I haven't checked it by myself, but you could give it a try.

[image: Dropbox Settings]

Comment: Disabling the Finder integration did not require a restart of either the Dropbox app, the Finder or the Mac - the changes were immediate when tested on Dropbox 8.4.21 and OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: As mentioned above i haven't tried it myself, but thanks for the correction on this point.

Comment: Not to pile on, but this doesn't address the OP's question as they specifically state they still want the integration, but without the icons.